# Create table - SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, keyword

can anyone tell me what I've done wrong? I've tried changing a few things around but I keep getting the same error so I'm convinced that I've forgotten something. I hope someone can help

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -


CREATE TABLE Player(
Plyr_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
Plyr_Fname NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_Sname NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_DOB date,
Plyr_Height DOUBLE,
Plyr_Weight double,
Plyr_position NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_experience int,
Team_ID INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_Team FOREIGN KEY (Team_ID) references Team(Team_ID)

);


Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Here's the Team table I'm referring to:

```
CREATE TABLE Team(
Team_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Team_Name NVARCHAR2(50),
Team_Homecourt nvarchar2(50)
);
```

Comment: [This data type information](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i54335) might be slightly more relevant. You can use `double precision` but unless you have a pressing need to make this compatible with other RDBMS, you might as well use Oracle types.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `double` you can try to use `NUMBER (precision, scale)`. So try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Player(
Plyr_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
Plyr_Fname NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_Sname NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_DOB date,
Plyr_Height NUMBER(7,2),    --Change as per your requirement.
Plyr_Weight NUMBER(7,2),
Plyr_position NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_experience int,
Team_ID INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_Team FOREIGN KEY (Team_ID) references Team(Team_ID)

);
```

**NOTE**: `double precision` is ANSI-supported datatypes whereas `NUMBER` is Oracle built-in datatypes

So if you want you can stick to double using precision as:

```
CREATE TABLE Player(
Plyr_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
Plyr_Fname NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_Sname NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_DOB date,
Plyr_Height DOUBLE PRECISION,
Plyr_Weight DOUBLE PRECISION,
Plyr_position NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_experience int,
Team_ID INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_Team FOREIGN KEY (Team_ID) references Team(Team_ID)
);
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you for responding so quickly and explaining it too, double precision worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use limit for int type...oracle will take default length for int type . Instead of int you can use Number type to make it run. And DOUBLE PRECISION is a data type in oracle but Double is not there.

```
CREATE TABLE Player(
Plyr_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
Plyr_Fname NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_Sname NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_DOB date,
Plyr_Height DOUBLE PRECISION,
Plyr_Weight DOUBLE PRECISION,
Plyr_position NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_experience int,
Team_ID INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_Team FOREIGN KEY (Team_ID) references Team(Team_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NUMBER (precision, scale) instead of DOUBLE

```
CREATE TABLE Player(
Plyr_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
Plyr_Fname NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_Sname NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_Dob Date,
Plyr_Height Number(10,2),
Plyr_Weight NUMBER(10,2),
Plyr_position NVARCHAR2(20),
Plyr_experience int,
Team_ID INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_Team FOREIGN KEY (Team_ID) references Team(Team_ID)

);
```