# I am trying to create a table in sql, but im missing a keyword, cant find out how to fix it

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I'm trying to create a table in SQL, but I'm missing a keyword, and I can't figure out how to fix it:

```
CREATE TABLE Attendance_of_employee
(
  supervisior VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'NONE',
  arrival double NOT NULL,
  shift_end double NOT NULL,
  date_time DATE NOT NULL,
  worked_hours INT NOT NULL,
  ID_record VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  employeeID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID_record),
  FOREIGN KEY (employeeID) REFERENCES EmployeeTAB(employeeID)
);

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00905: chýbajúce kľúčové slovo
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: It seems you have to change double. Here is a link
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36424127/7623263

Comment: Why are arrival and shift end of data type number, and not date? That would make much more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you usually use `number` for numeric values and `varchar2()` for character strings.  I would always have the primary key be the first column in the table.  So:

```
CREATE TABLE Attendance_of_employee (
  ID_record VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  supervisior VARCHAR2(30) DEFAULT 'NONE',
  arrival number NOT NULL,
  shift_end number NOT NULL,
  date_time DATE NOT NULL,
  worked_hours INT NOT NULL,
  employeeID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID_record),
  FOREIGN KEY (employeeID) REFERENCES EmployeeTAB(employeeID)
);
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/BGASOI77880) is a link in Rextester (without the foreign key relationship, because `EmployeeTAB` is not defined).

Answer (score 1):

Use double precision instead of double.

```
CREATE TABLE Attendance_of_employee( supervisior VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'NONE', 
arrival double precision NOT NULL, 
shift_end double precision NOT NULL, date_time DATE NOT NULL, 
worked_hours INT NOT NULL, 
ID_record VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, employeeID INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID_record), 
FOREIGN KEY (employeeID) REFERENCES EmployeeTAB(employeeID) );
```